# @Before/@BeforeClass seems not working, objects indicates on null

Tags: java, junit

i'm learning junit and problem have occured at the beginning.

At the start i want to initialize objected which will be used in tests.
But @BeforeClass doesn't do that.

```
public class InitTests {
private Croupier croupier;
private Player p1, p2;
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    croupier = new Croupier();
    croupier.PlayersInit(5, 100);
    p1 = croupier.getPlayer(0);
    p2 = croupier.getPlayer(1);
} @Test // p1,p2, croupier = null, have no idea why.
public void PlayerInitTest() {
    assertEquals(0, p1.getId());
    assertEquals(1, p2.getId());
}}
```

Other classes :

```
public class Player {

private ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();
private int coins = 0;
private static int playerNumber = 0;
private int id;
private boolean inGame = true;

public Player(int coins) {
    this.coins = coins;
    id = ++playerNumber;
}

public int addCoins(int amount) {
    coins+=amount;
    return amount;
}

public int substractCoins(int substract) {
    coins-=substract;
    return substract;
}

public int getCoins() {
    return coins;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean isInGame() {
    return inGame;
}

public void setGameStatus(boolean status) {
    if(getCoins() < 0 )
        inGame = false;
    else 
        inGame = status;
}

public void clearHand() {
    hand.clear();
}}

public class Croupier {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Player> actual = new ArrayList<>();
private int stack = 0;
private int bigPlayerStack = 0;
private int smallPlayerStack = 0;

public Croupier() {
    System.out.println("tutej.");
}

public Croupier CroupierInit() {
    // static
    PlayersInit(5, 100);

    return new Croupier();
}

private void CreateDeck() {
    String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };

    for (int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
        for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
            deck.add(new Card(j, suits[i]));

}

private void DeckShuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
}

public boolean TurnPlayed() {
    if (!preparedGame())
        return false;

    return true;

}

public void StartGame() {
    preparedGame();
    System.out.println("Game ended.");
}

public boolean preparedGame() {
    clearTable();

    if(!setActualPlayers()) 
        return false;

    setSmallAndBig();
    takeFromSmallAndBig();
    CreateDeck();
    DeckShuffle();

    return true;
}

// set players who are playing
public boolean setActualPlayers() {
    for (Player e : allPlayers)
        if (e.isInGame())
            actual.add(e);

    if (actual.size() < 2)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// take coisn from small and big blind
public void takeFromSmallAndBig() {
    stack += actual.get(bigPlayerStack).substractCoins(20);
    stack += actual.get(smallPlayerStack).substractCoins(10);
}

// set who has small or big blind
public void setSmallAndBig() {
    bigPlayerStack++;
    if (bigPlayerStack > actual.size())
        bigPlayerStack = 0;

    smallPlayerStack = bigPlayerStack - 1;

    if(smallPlayerStack < 0 )
        smallPlayerStack = actual.size() -1;
}

// clear table before game
public void clearTable() {
    actual.clear();
    for (Player e : allPlayers)
        e.clearHand();
}

public void PlayersInit(int numberOfPlayers, int coins) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        allPlayers.add(new Player(coins));
    }
}

public Player getPlayer(int index) {
    return allPlayers.get(index);
}}
```

I'm sure these tests are correct because when i put setUp method ( code from that method) inside @Test it just works.
I hope it's a simple syntax problem which as a beginner can't set at the moment.

Greetings.

Comment: `@BeforeClass` methods need to be static. For what you have here, use `@Before`.

Comment: Doesn't work either :(

Comment: Which version of JUnit do you use? Could we see the import for `@BeforeClass` and `@Test`?

Comment: Sure :)
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import Implementation.Croupier;

import Implementation.Player;

I

Comment: ok, so you mixed JUnit 4 and 5 annotations - you need to import annotations from `*.jupiter.*` packages. Try `@BeforeEach` or `@BeforeAll`, with a static method for the latter. (I assumed your JUnit launcher is using version 5 if your test executes, because it is annotated with a Junit 5 `@Test`. If this isn't the case or isn't what you want - revert all the annotations to JUnit 4).

Comment: Are you running them with Eclipse ? Sometime, even if you include the good version of the library junit, Eclipse is configured to run it with an older version (junit 3).
You can see it here: "right click on your project" > Run As > Run Configuration > "Your test" under Junit > Test runner: (JUnit 4, 3...).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your test class uses a mix of JUnit 4 and 5 annotations.

The JUnit 5 API is not compatible with prior versions of the library, and defines a new set of annotations. Assuming your test executes, you are probably using a JUnit 5 launcher and therefore need to use annotations from [`org.junit.jupiter.api`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/package-summary.html) package.

**If you wish to use JUnit 5**
Try `@org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach` or`@org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll`, with a static method for the latter. Their semantic is defined [here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).

**If you wish to use JUnit 4**
You need revert all the annotations to JUnit 4 - which implies using `org.junit.Test`.
Your JUnit launcher needs to be configured for JUnit 4.